# Aggregate function returns inaccurate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get item balance

```
where balance = SUM(pod.Quantity) + SUM(iob.OpeningBalance)
```

The query returns the following output:

```
ItemName   Balance
------------------
Item1        35
```

but it supposed to be

```
ItemName   Balance
------------------
Item1         25
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    i.ItemName,
    SUM(pod.Quantity) + SUM(iob.OpeningBalance) AS Balance
FROM 
    dbo.Items i
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.PurchaseOrderDetails pod ON i.ItemID = pod.ItemID
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemOpeningBalances iob ON i.ItemID = iob.ItemID
GROUP BY 
    i.ItemName
```

`Items` table:

```
+--------+----------+
| ItemID | ItemName |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Item1    | 
+--------+----------+
```

`ItemOpeningBalances` table:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| OpeningBalanceID  | ItemID          | OpeningBalance  |       
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|                 1 |  1              |      10         |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

`PurchaseOrderDetails` table:

```
+-----------------------+--------+----------+
| PurchaseOrderDetailID | ItemID | Quantity |
+-----------------------+--------+----------+
|                    1  | Item1  |        5 |           
|                    2  | Item1  |       10 |                 
+-----------------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: its because the without `group by` the query will return 2 rows with opening balance 10 in both rows and quantity as 5 and 10. when you group opening balance becomes 20 a quantity 15. Since both these things are logically separate you should separate them in 2 queries and not group them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you query are adding up the opening balance for every lines of PurchaseOrderDetails.

Change to using sub query on the PurchaseOrderDetails

```
SELECT 
  i.ItemName,
  --SUM(pod.Quantity) + SUM(iob.OpeiningBalance) AS Balance
  (pod.Quantity) + (iob.OpeiningBalance) AS Balance
FROM dbo.Items i
left JOIN 
( -- change to sum it in the sub query
  select ItemId, Quantity  = sum(Quantity)
  from dbo.PurchaseOrderDetails 
  group by ItemId
) pod
  ON i.ItemID = pod.ItemID
  left JOIN ItemOpeningBalances iob
  ON i.ItemID = iob.ItemID
--GROUP BY i.ItemName,
--         i.ItemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT 
  i.ItemName,
  pod.PurQuantity + iob.OpeiningBalance AS Balance
FROM dbo.Items i
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(pod.Quantity) AS PurQuantity 
            FROM dbo.PurchaseOrderDetails p
            WHERE i.ItemID = p.ItemID
            ) as pod
left JOIN ItemOpeningBalances iob
ON i.ItemID = iob.ItemID
```